# Why try-except syntax error occurred (python)?

Tags: python

```
def insurance_calculator():
    while True:
        try:
            A = int(input('현재 나이가 어떻게 되나요? '))
            if A <= 0:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print('ERROR: 잘못된 숫자입니다!', end='\n\n')
            continue
        while True:
            G = input("당신은 '여자'입니까 '남자'입니까? ")
            if G != '남자' and G != '여자':
                print("ERROR: '여자' 또는 '남자'를 입력하세요!")
            else:
                break
        try:
            M = int(input('매년 보험금으로 얼마를 지불할 예정입니까? '))
            if M <= 0:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print('ERROR: 잘못된 숫자입니다!', end='\n\n')
            continue
        try:
            R = float(input('현재 이자율은 얼마입니까? ')
        except ValueError:
            print('ERROR: 잘못된 숫자입니다!', end='\n\n')
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Syntax Error occurs on the last except.(Solving for 4~5hrs) (Indentation error not occurred) How could I solve the problem?

Comment: What does the error message say if you remove the custom handling?

Comment: `R = float(input('현재 이자율은 얼마입니까? ')` has an unbalanced parenthesis. Add a `)` and it might work.

Comment: It's a typo, as @HampusLarsson mentioned

Comment: It works! Typo was the cause. Thanks a lot :D